# Deploying a Java Applet with a signed jar

Tags: html, deployment, jar, jar-signing, signed-applet

I have been learning how to deploy applets.  I have put my code in a jar, have signed it and now I am trying to put it on weebly.com.  The error in the java console says that the Minesweeper.class cannot be found.  I believe I have the codebase pointing to the right folder. Thanks for any help.

```
<applet code = "Minesweeper.class"
    codebase = "lbushmanportfolio.weebly.com/uploads/1/2/7/5/12755120/"
    archive = "Minesweeper.jar"
    width = "550"
    height = "580">
</applet>
```

Comment: If at `weebly.com` the code base should be `http://lbushmanportfolio.weebly.com/uploads/1/2/7/5/12755120/` or `/lbushmanportfolio.weebly.com/uploads/1/2/7/5/12755120/`.  Also, `http://lbushmanportfolio.weebly.com/uploads/1/2/7/5/12755120/Minesweeper.jar` is a 404.  Where can we see the HTML fail?

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I didn't see your comment till now.  I solved my issue about an hour ago.  Weebly automatically lowercased Minesweeper.jar, which makes sense why they do.  Also, I believe I tried the codebase with "http://..." before but it didn't work. This time I just gave a relative URL. So I put "/uploads/1/2/7/5/12755120/" as the codebase and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The error in the java console says that the Minesweeper.class cannot be found.

That is not surprising, given http://lbushmanportfolio.weebly.com/uploads/1/2/7/5/12755120/Minesweeper.jar is a 404.

---

BTW - why is the applet digitally signed?  Here is what I see when I **refuse** the digitally signed code.

[image: MineField]

To put that another way, the basics of the game seem to work fine in sand-boxed code.  OTOH, if a non Oracle JRE user refused the digitally signed code (e.g. an 'Iced Tea' JRE user), the applet would not be loaded at all!

Comment: Yeah, I had the applet working perfectly just running from the appletviewer.  When I was deploying it I was wondering if by chance that it wasn't working because it wasn't signed.  It was just one of the few things that I tried.  I later realized I didn't need to but hadn't changed it.  Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: Cool.  Glad you got a solution.  BTW - applets will cause a lot more head-aches, and provide a lesser user experience, than a `JFrame` launched from a link using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).